# Two SecurityFilterChain with two difference Authentication

Tags: spring, security

I have two securityFilterChain
One ("/api/**") using UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter with  and another ("/bo/ **")for ResourceServer which is using jwt
But the first one is working fine.
The second is not working.

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(WHITE_LIST_CORS_URL));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "x-auth-token"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "DELETE"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3000L);
    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URL).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
    .and().cors().configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration).and()
    .csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
    .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
    .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).headers()
    .frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    
    return http.build();
}
    
@Bean
@Order(2)
SecurityFilterChain boSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
     http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/bo/**").access("hasAuthority('SCOPE_products.read')")
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    return http.build();
}
```

I want below code should work

```
@Bean
@Order(2)
SecurityFilterChain boSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
         http
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/bo/**").access("hasAuthority('SCOPE_products.read')")
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .oauth2ResourceServer()
         .jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your beans to be applied to a particular path. Use `http.securityMatcher(pathMatchers("/api/**"))` in your first SecurityFilterChain bean. The same way with `/bo/**` in the second one.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-security-matchers